# Redis Error reading from the server: Connection reset by peer

Tags: redis

I want use pipe mode insert some data to redis.
 When I run

```
cat test-TXT.txt |./redis-4.0.1/src/redis-cli -h 10.99.205.240 --pipe
```

I get this error:

> Error reading from the server: Connection reset by peer

This is test-Txt.txt content:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsVK0.png)

Redis.conf :

```
protected-mode no
bind 10.99.205.240
```

other configuration used default.
I can use logstash insert data to redis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat test-TXT.txt; sleep 5 |./redis-4.0.1/src/redis-cli -h 10.99.205.240 --pipe
```

Maybe it is because when cat process is done, it exits and cause the child process redis-cli exits also. So add sleep 5 to wait for reply.

Comment: this solution is work.i don't get any error.but i get this:All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 0.I do not insert any data.Maybe i get something woring in test-TXT.txt

Comment: have you checked the `testpipemode` with redis-cli? something like `lrange testpipemode 0 -1`

Comment: yes,I run "llen testpipemode" on redis-cli and it return "(integer) 0".I change test-TXT.txt and I also change the test-TXT.txt content picture in the Question.I dont know "<cr><lf>" and "\r\n" whitch one is what i shuold write in test-TXT.txt?

Comment: could you share this text with github or gist?

Comment: i'm sorry for reply so late.This is github URL : https://github.com/AlexRITIAN/Redis-test-pipemod

Comment: I resolution this problem.I write 'LPUSH key value\r\n' in test-TXT file and run command : cat test-TXT | redis-cli --pipe and It success.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're using '\r\n' as line separator. Otherwise you can get into problems.
You can verify if you are having errors removing --pipe:

```
cat test-TXT.txt | redis-cli -h 10.99.205.240
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as line-separators, any other error in the protocol text will cause this error - including if the number after `*` or `$` is wrong compared to the actual data.